The type or namespace could not be found
Ошибка 1:

Assets/Scripts/Importing/LoadingThread.cs(8,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StartupSingleton<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Ошибка 2:

Assets/Scripts/Importing/LoadingThread.cs(10,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BackgroundJobRunner' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Ошибка 3:

Assets/Scripts/Importing/LoadingThread.cs(47,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BackgroundJobRunner' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Код:

`using UGameCore.Utilities;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


namespace SanAndreasUnity.Importing
{

  public class LoadingThread : StartupSingleton<LoadingThread>
  {
      public BackgroundJobRunner BackgroundJobRunner { get; } = new BackgroundJobRunner();
      
      public ushort maxTimePerFrameMs = 0;



#if UNITY_EDITOR
      [UnityEditor.InitializeOnLoadMethod]
      static void InitOnLoadInEditor()
        {
          if (null == Singleton)
              return;

          Singleton.BackgroundJobRunner.EnsureBackgroundThreadStarted();
        }
#endif

      protected override void OnSingletonStart()
      {
          this.BackgroundJobRunner.EnsureBackgroundThreadStarted();
      }

      protected override void OnSingletonDisable()
      {
          this.BackgroundJobRunner.ShutDown();
      }

      void Update()
        {
          this.UpdateJobs();
        }

      public void UpdateJobs()
      {
          this.BackgroundJobRunner.UpdateJobs(this.maxTimePerFrameMs);
      }

      public static void RegisterJob<T>(BackgroundJobRunner.Job<T> job)
        {
          ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnMainThread(); // obtaining Singleton should only happen on main thread

          Singleton.BackgroundJobRunner.RegisterJob(job);
      }

  }

}
`


